# Version of Gradle to use with Gradle Experimental Plugin

Tags: android, gradle

I'm having a hard time searching for the documentation of the Gradle Experimental plugin, that I'm trying to use in Android Studio. Looking at Bintray, on the following page:

https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle-experimental/view

It tells me that the last stable version of the gradle-experimental plugin is 0.9.3. However, when I search online for which version of Gradle would match with the gradle-experimental plugin, I can't find that information anywhere. The last scrap of information I found is here:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

And it says that the plugin version 0.7.3 should be matched with Gradle 2.14.1. I couldn't find anything more recent.

Any help on this issue would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: When I updated my version of the gradle-experimental plugin to '0.9.3' I got the message that I needed to update my gradle plugin to '2.3.3'. I did so and it apparently works. However, I haven't gotten my build to work yet, so I'm not putting that as an answer yet. Once I get my build to work, I'll come back and put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am using gradle-experimental:0.11.1 with gradle version 4.1 and it works.

Comment: What version of Android Studio have you gotten this to work on, and were you able to codesign an APK with it?

Comment: i think it was with AS 3.1

Comment: but you can get rid of it and migrate to cmake

Comment: I have a bounty on my question on the topic here, BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58565006/how-can-i-codesign-a-64-bit-android-apk-using-the-gradle-experimental-plugin

Comment: i removed gradle experimental and migrated to cmake, then i could build for every ABI ("x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a")